# How to assign permissions to manage windows service when UAC is enabled?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, uac, windows-services

I have following scenario:

- I'm local admin on my computer with Windows 7 Enterprise and UAC enabled
- Computer is not in domain and is not under group policy
- I run some program without running it as administrator
- This program sometimes needs to control locally installed windows service (with Manual start options)
- Without running initial program as administrator or without disabling UAC controlling windows service fails.

How can I grant permissions to my account to control this particular service without running with elevated privileges or disabling UAC?

Comment: The qeuestion is how are you running it (running it from a batch file using a scheduled task?)? and when (startup shutdown)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services, just like about every Windows object, have an ACL associated with it, which can be modified to give you access.

As far as I know, there is no official UI for managing service ACLs, so you're left with two options:

1. Download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Start your service (ProcExp only shows running services). In ProcExp, double-click on the process for the Service (or right-click and click Properties). Click the "Services" tab. Typically your program is run by a particular user - Add that user. Hit Advanced. The permissions you can manage include stop/start of this Service and sending custom-defined commands to it.

   [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is similar, but can manage stopped services as well.
2. `sc sdshow`, learn the [ACE syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374928%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [access rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374902%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), edit the security descriptor, pass it back to `sc sdset`.

Comment: For the above Service approach, setting Custom commands permissions http://i.imgur.com/tql3pUA.png