# Is it possible to give a user admin privledges over a service?

Tags: windows-vista, permissions, windows-services, coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign permissions to manage windows service when UAC is enabled?](https://superuser.com/questions/315705/how-to-assign-permissions-to-manage-windows-service-when-uac-is-enabled)

Our network admin set the ColdFusion 9 Application Server service to start automatically, sometimes the service starts and sometime it doesn't. So is there a way to give a user permissions over a specific service? Any other proposed solutions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with [the Group Policy Editor](http://www.theeldergeek.com/group_policy_editor.htm), you can implement a GP to allow certain a user (group) access to start/stop a particular service.  For more details, see [this thread](http://forums.techarena.in/active-directory/1063729.htm).  I'm not sure if you can do this remotely, but I know it is possible on a local policy basis.

Comment: This is a lot more complicated, but if he wants to try it this way, this is a better guide: http://serverfault.com/questions/55961/is-it-possible-to-use-group-policy-to-grant-the-permission-to-manage-windows-serv

Answer (score 2):

I might approach this task a bit differently: I would consider just setting up a scheduled task to run a batch file with `net start service` as an administrator every minute.

It is not exactly processor intensive, and if it is already started, it will do nothing. I would put the batch file used to start the service in a location that is secured for administrator only so it cannot be edited to change what it is doing.

This way you also do not have to worry about it not starting if someone is not there to do it manually.